# Подскажите фреймворк для работы по паттерну MVP/MVC

Tags: android, mvp

Подскажите какие есть фреймворки для работы по паттернам MVP/MVC?

Планирую писать приложение менеджер-паролей. Основной целью является обучение.
Хотелось бы посмотреть как это делается в специализированных фреймворках.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, в целом Android - это сам по себе MVC уже. Вьюхи у вас в xml. `Activity` и фрагменты, по сути - контроллеры. Надо только модели реализовать и данные забиндить.

Если очень нужен именно фреймворк, то есть, к примеру, [AndroidMvc](https://github.com/kejunxia/AndroidMvc)
.